# Best practice between Dictionary<string, string> and Struct with String

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, struct

I am currently creating a project that fills a CSV file using a DataTable.

Here is a basic example of the creation of the DataTable (but mine has around 40 lines, here is just basic example).

```
DataTable outputFile = new DataTable("title");
outputFile.Columns.Add("Col A", typeof(string));
outputFile.Columns.Add("Col B", typeof(string));
outputFile.Columns.Add("Col C", typeof(string));
outputFile.Columns.Add("Col D", typeof(string));
outputFile.Columns.Add("Col E", typeof(string));
```

To fill the data table, I am currently hesitating between two solutions :

- A Static Dictionary that I create in the class containing the DataTable, or

  ```
  public static Dictionary<string, string> newRow { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
      {"col a", ""},
      {"col b", ""},
      {"col c", ""},
      {"col d", ""},
      {"col e", ""}
  };
  ```
- A Struct filled with string.

  ```
  public struct newRowStruct{
      public string colA;
      public string colB;
      public string colC;
      public string colD;
      public string colE;

  }
  ```

This will then be used in a method to add rows to my DataStruct.

Which one will be the best design practice and why ?

Comment: A `Dictionary` and a `struct` are two completely different things which serve two completely different purposes. In my experience I've only ever needed to create a struct a handful of times to deal with P/Invoke. You want to use a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The only problem I can see if I use a dictionary is that I have to handle the errors (i.e.  key not existing in the dictionary). This cannot happen when using a Struct because Visual Studio will flag it as an error.